# PostgreSQL timestamp/numeric precision ignored on function parameter?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.3

Given the following PostgreSQL functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_dtm (
    dtm timestamptz(0))
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'fn: %, %', dtm, dtm::timestamptz(0);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_num (
    num numeric(5, 2))
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'num: %, %', num, num::numeric(5, 2);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Would you expect the output of these functions to show the result as per the type declared in the function parameter?

I was very surprised to find that the precision was retained and shown in the "NOTICE" despite the parameter type limiting the precision.

Is this a bug or am I just thinking about it the wrong way?

```
Here is the output:

db=> SELECT fn_dtm(now());
NOTICE:  fn: 2015-02-05 10:25:44.184+00, 2015-02-05 10:25:44+00

db=> SELECT fn_num(1.23456789);
NOTICE:  num: 1.23456789, 1.23
```

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.

**EDIT:**
If I do this I get what I expect:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_dtm (
    dtm timestamptz(0))
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    dtm = dtm::timestamptz(0); ----- CHANGE PRECISION
    RAISE NOTICE 'fn: %', dtm;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Gives:

```
db=> SELECT fn_dtm(now());
NOTICE:  fn: 2015-02-05 10:38:38+00
```

Comment: It affects `sql` functions too. I haven't found any direct reference to this in the manual, but *sizing casts* only mentioned in the [Value Storage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-query.html) section of the *Type Conversion* chapter; which suggests to me, that scale/precision is only applied, if it is on a table's column (or if you use an explicit sizing cast, like you tried).

Comment: Thanks pozs and Nick.  I've sent an email off to them anyway just to mention that it should probably be documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not what you'd expect, but that's the way it works.

The cause is clear if you ask Postgres for the function's definition; run `\sf fn_num` in psql, or `SELECT pg_get_functiondef('fn_num'::regproc)`, and it will give you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_num(num numeric) ...
```

So by the time Postgres creates your function, the precision/scale information has already been discarded. Return types suffer from the same issue.

It is possible to work around this by using domains to alias the types involved:

```
CREATE DOMAIN timestamptz_seconds AS timestamptz(0);
CREATE FUNCTION fn_dtm(dtm timestamptz_seconds) ...
```

This can be particularly useful for return types if you need to retain the precision in the definition of your result set. But in most cases, as you pointed out, you can get the same outcome with some explicit casts in your function body.

Comment: Thanks for that, it taught me a couple of things I didn't know too :-)